# how I can print a document pdf from exec PHP?

Tags: php, batch-file

I am trying to print a pdf document from exec function with a .bat file :

```
$resultado=exec("test.bat");
```

The .bat file content is:

```
start AcroRd32.exe /p /h "C:\documents\documento.pdf" "\\direccion_ip\nombre_impresora"
taskkill /im AcroRd32.exe
```

When I open the .bat file, this prints, but not when I send the command via php.

Also, I tried with `popen` :

```
$bat_filename = "C:\\printer.bat";

if( pclose(popen($bat_filename, 'r')) ) 
    echo "print";
else
  echo "no print ";
```

The content printer.bat is :

```
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat Reader DC\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe /p /h "C:\documents\document.pdf" "\\path_printer\printer_name"
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Does your web server even have a printer?

Comment: @SLaks: well, if the bare batch file works …

Comment: @OskarGalvis: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: SLaks, No It does not .  But I  run the file .bat and the document print !, cuz I have:  "\\remote_ip\printer_name" .  But in the PHP file It's not run !

Comment: @lxg  No, The process not display any error !  ...